# Returning string result into a new line in a table cell

Tags: javascript, xml, string, jdbc

I have this data that i need to split into 3 lines within the same cell.

```
 var Ms = '<tr>'
    Ms += '<td>' + 'Where' + '\n\r' + 'are' + '\n\r' + 'you' + '</td>';
    Ms += '</tr>'
```

I tried \n, \r and \n\r but seems not to work.
I need the result in this format:
Where
are
you

Comment: use </br>. if your browser interprets html, then br will be fine.

Comment: For one strange reason, i don't know why i thought that cannot solve the problem. Apparently, it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `<br>`

```
 var Ms = '<tr>'
    Ms += '<td>' + 'Where' + '<br>' + 'are' + '<br>' + 'you' + '</td>';
    Ms += '</tr>'
```